# Why isn't the FileList object an array?

Tags: javascript

Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList

Why is `FileList` an object rather than an array? The only property it has is `.length` and the only method it has is `.item()`, which is redundant (`fileList[0] === fileList.item(0)`).

Comment: Many APIs related to DOM and HTML are defined in a more data-structure-agnostic way. Think about `NodeList`s and `HTMLCollection`s. E.g. what if a language doesn't support the `foo[bar]` syntax?

Answer (score 180, accepted):

Well, there could be several reasons. For one, if it were an array, you could modify it. You can't modify a `FileList` instance. Secondly but related, it could be (probably is) a view onto a browser data structure, so a minimal set of capabilities makes it easier for implementations to provide it.

You can convert it to an array via `a = Array.from(theFileList)` (that's an ES2015 method, but it's trivial to polyfill it) or via `a = Array.prototype.slice.call(theFileList)`.

**Update in 2018:** Interestingly, though, [the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#filelist-section) has a note on `FileList`:

> The `FileList` interface should be considered "at risk" since the general trend on the Web Platform is to replace such interfaces with the `Array` platform object in ECMAScript [ECMA-262]. In particular, this means syntax of the sort `filelist.item(0)` is at risk; most other programmatic use of `FileList` is unlikely to be affected by the eventual migration to an `Array` type.

I find that note odd. I thought the trend was toward `iterable`, not `Array` — such as the update to [`NodeList`](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-nodelist) marking it `iterable` for compatibility with spread syntax, `for-of`, and `forEach`.

Comment: Since you can't modify it, there's no reason for it to have `.push()` and other array methods.

Comment: @VladimirKornea (time passes but...) well I have the use-case of validating file sizes, so "filter" from Array comes in handy. There are many others "read-only" methods.

Comment: Does the note mean it would be risky to use `Array.from(theFileList)`? Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Crashalot - No, that should be just fine. I can't imagine `FileList` itself going away (though I could be wrong -- as the note says, most people's code treats it like an array), but apparently the `item` method may since it's not widely used. But the object will be there and be array-like, so `Array.from(theFileList)` gets you from the possibly-changing thing (the `FileList`) to a nice well-defined thing (an array).

Comment: Thanks for the fast response and clarification. OK, we'll stick to using `Array.from(theFileList)` since it's not an actual array and we need it as an array for concatenation purposes.

Answer (score 28):

I think it's its own Datatype because Object Oriented Programming was more of a thing than functional programming back when it was defined. Modern Javascript offers functionality to cast Array-like Datatypes to Arrays.

For example, like Tim described: 
`const files = [...filesList]`

Another way of iterating a FileList with ES6 is the Array.from() method.

`const fileListAsArray = Array.from(fileList)`

IMO it's more readable than the spread operator, but on the other hand it's longer code :)

Comment: It's true they tried to make JS look like Javas dumb little brother. I don't think though, OO at to blame here - the irony is that in many aspects Java itself wasn't very consistent in being object oriented. And I'd argue `FileList` not being an array is questionable especially from an OO standpoint. Other stuff as well, like having a dedicated `Math` object (that sorta made sense in Java) leaked through, even though with JS only number type this could have been done better. I guess it's all a consequence of being designed in a rush.

Answer (score 7):

If you want use array methods on FileList try `apply`

So for example:

`Array.prototype.every.call(YourFileList, file => { ... })`

if you want to use every

Answer (score 2):

Here's a couple of polyfills that add a `toObject()` function to `File` and a `toArray()` function to `FileList`:

```
File.prototype.toObject = function () {
  return Object({
    lastModified: parseInt(this.lastModified),
    lastModifiedDate: String(this.lastModifiedDate),
    name: String(this.name),
    size: parseInt(this.size),
    type: String(this.type)
  })
}

FileList.prototype.toArray = function () {
  return Array.from(this).map(function (file) {
    return file.toObject()
  })
}

var files = document.getElementById('file-upload').files
var fileObject = files[0].toObject()
var filesArray = files.toArray()
```