# Add attachments to attachments array

Tags: javascript

I have the below function that adds attachments from an `<input type="file" multiple />` to a parent's state.

That works fine until the user wants to add another attachment/s, the new attachment/s override the existing ones, how can I have the new attachments be added to the existing attachments array?

```
handleAddAttachments = fileList => {
  this.props.handleChange('attachments', Array.from(fileList));
};
```

I tried that but it doesn't seem to work.

```
handleAddAttachments = fileList => {
  const { attachments } = this.props.ticket;
  this.props.handleChange('attachments', [...attachments, fileList]);
};
```

The parent `handleChange` function:

```
makeHandleChange = (pageName, change) => {
  this.setState({
    ticket: { ...this.state.ticket, [pageName]: change },
  });
};
```

Comment: If you ```console.log([...attachments, fileList])``` do you see the expected result?

Comment: @sigmus, no, let's say I first added 3 attachments and then added a 4th one, I see a `[{"0": {},"1": {},"2": {}}{"0": {}}]` instead of `[{},{},{},{}]` that I would expected to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second version you are missing the `Array.from()` part. The change from a fileInput is not directly an array, so the spread operator does not work.

This should do the trick:

```
handleAddAttachments = fileList => {
  const { attachments } = this.props.ticket;
  this.props.handleChange('attachments', [...attachments, ...Array.from(fileList)]);
};
```

For further information why it is not an array, you can find some information here: [Why isn't the FileList object an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25333488/why-isnt-the-filelist-object-an-array)

Thanks @sigmus, I added the missing spread to the `Array.from()`

Comment: I have tried that too, the result is first `[[{},{},{},{}]]` instead of `[{},{},{},{}]`, then when I add a new attachment the result is: `[[{},{},{},{}],[{}]]`instead of `[{},{},{},{},{}]`

Comment: And if you also spread Array.from, like ```[...attachments, ...Array.from(fileList)]```?

Comment: @NicolasGehlert please update your question so I can accept it